# this code in jquery giving me all element i clicked by class name a2 instead of giving me unique a2 result

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

i was expecting one a2 element at a time on clicking one div element but i am getting all a2 element at once
i want one a2 class element at a time by clicking on it

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> Login Form in HTML5 and CSS3</title>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="a1" > <div class="a2"  onclick="on()"> eq </div> </div>
<div class="a4" > <div class="a2" onclick="on()"   > dwqr </div> </div>
   <p id="demo"> i am hare </p>



 <script>
function on() 
{
    var b=  $(".a2").click(function(){
      $(this);
  });

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =b.text();
}
 </script>
<style>
 .a1
 {
    width:310px;
    height:310px;
    border:2px solid red;
 }
 .a4
 {
    width:310px;
    height:310px;
    border:2px solid red;
 }
 .a2
 {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    border:2px solid red;
    padding-left: 50px;
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
      text-indent:-9999px;
    
    }
</style>
</body>
</html>
```

i was expecting one a2 element at a time on clicking one div element but i am getting all a2 element at once
i want one a2 class element at a time by clicking on it

Comment: This code is gibberish. You don't need `onclick="on()` _and_ `$(".a2").click` at the same time. They both do the same job. And putting one inside the other is even stranger.  Also `$(this);` on its own does nothing at all. Review your understanding of event handlers, choose a style (inline or unobtrusive - most people would adivse the latter) and stick to it. Also, make up your mind whether you're using jQuery or native JS and - again - stick to one style, then your code is more consistent, readable, maintable and comprehensible.

Comment: `<script>
    $(".a2").click(function(){
      $(this);
     $("#demo").html($(this).text());
  });
 </script>` and remove the `onclick` attributes from the buttons, would likely make most sense.

Comment: Also this has absolutely nothing to do with PHP, I retagged it for you. See also [ask] and related materials

Comment: i want this to work when some one clicks it that's why onclick="on()"

Comment: Have a good read of https://api.jquery.com/ and make sure you understand the functions and how to actually use them, look carefully at examples, and take some jQuery tutorials. Then hopefully you won't fall down this rabbit-hole of random nonsensical code again in future. It looked, frankly, like the product of complete guesswork without any actual understanding. You cannot write progams by copy-and-paste alone.

Comment: `I wsant this to work when some one clicks it that's why onclick="on()"`...sure, but jquery's `.click()` does exactly the same job. If you didn't understand that, what did you think the `.click()` bit was for, and why did you add it to your code? Don't add code if you don't know what it is! Don't guess, read the documentation: https://api.jquery.com/click/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need any of the `onclick` stuff, and it's considered a bit obsolete anyway (although arguably so is jQuery, these days). Simply us the unobtrusive event handler.

Demo using jQuery:

```js
$(".a2").click(function() {
  $("#demo").html($(this).text());
});
```

```css
.a2 {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title> Login Form in HTML5 and CSS3</title>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="a1">
    <div class="a2"> eq </div>
  </div>
  <div class="a4">
    <div class="a2"> dwqr </div>
  </div>
  <p id="demo"> i am hare </p>
</body>
```

Demo using only native JS:

```js
var divs = document.querySelectorAll(".a2");
divs.forEach(function(div) {
  div.addEventListener("click", function(el) {
    document.querySelector("#demo").innerHTML = this.innerText;
  });
});
```

```css
.a2 {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title> Login Form in HTML5 and CSS3</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="a1">
    <div class="a2"> eq </div>
  </div>
  <div class="a4">
    <div class="a2"> dwqr </div>
  </div>
  <p id="demo"> i am hare </p>
</body>
```

Comment: i want to get it inside script tag as var a value

Comment: So assign it to a variable instead of writing it to the demo element then. My example replicated the intended outcome of your original code, not functionality you didn't mention at any point previously :-)

Comment: give me that value inside script tag i am not able to get it

Comment: Sorry I don't know what you mean. Please explain more clearly

Comment: var a= $(".a2").click(function() {
  $("#demo").html($(this).text());
});   in this code i want onclick a2 it give me unique class a2 value inside script as var a so that i can make it a session value sessionStorage.setItem("data", a)

Comment: `$(this).text()` returns the text from the clicked item. Read jquery documentation to understand what `this` means and what `.text()` means

Comment: And any basic javascript tutorial will show you how to assign a variable using `var x = y;` syntax...there should be no reason to be stuck on something as basic as that (unless you are just trying to learn JS by copy-and-paste instead of by actually studying it, of course!). But then again, you don't _need_ to assign it to anything, just put the output of `.text()` directly into the session storage call.

Comment: e.g. `sessionStorage.setItem("data", $(this).text())` . After all, why use up extra memory or code with a variable you don't actually need?

Comment: hay why don't you solve my this problem it will be a lot of help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75783659/on-click-on-outer-div-inner-div-value-is-fetched-if-i-click-an-a1-of-first-first

Comment: I literally just did. See my last comment here. `sessionStorage.setItem("data", $(this).text())` - put that _inside_ the `click(function() { ... }` area

Comment: `var a = $(".a2").click(function(){
    $(this);
    });` makes no sense. And putting `.click()` inside a function called from on `onclick` also makes no sense (you are duplicating the same thing!). I already explained that here on this post - and showed you how to do it correctly, but it seems that you didn't listen. In your version, `a` will contain a jQuery object pointing to the elements matched by a2. It doesn't tell you their values.

Comment: Please pay attention properly to everything I have said here, and read https://api.jquery.com/click/ , and look properly at examples online. I will say it again: you cannot learn to program by guessing, and without studying.

Comment: on that post i want on click on outer div inner div value is fetched i am trying to fetch inner div value uniquely when i click on class a1 div i want it to give me first first value  and first second value but it is giving me first first value and second first value means all a2 and on click second a1 class i want it to give me second first value and second second value but it is giving me all a4 means first second value and second second value and i want it to work one by one but it is working simultaneously there are two a1 and i want which a1 work that i clicked not that i not clicked

Comment: I already answered your other question with a full demo...did you notice? And it fetches the values one by one based on the specific item clicked.

Comment: P.S. `but it is giving me first first value and second first value means all a2`...I don't know which code you think is doing that? Your code simply doesn't work (and makes no sense), and nothing I've provided you with does what you're describing. So I don't even know what code you're actually talking about (and you didn't think to clarify it)