# on click on outer div inner div value is fetched if i click an a1 of first first value i want it to give first first & first s. valu inside script tag

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title> Login Form in HTML5 and CSS3</title>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="a1" onclick="on()">
  <div class="a2" > first first value </div> 
  <div class="a4" > first second value </div> 
</div>
<div class="a1" onclick="on()"> 
  <div class="a2" > second first value </div> 
  <div class="a4" > second second value </div> 
</div>

<script>
function on() 
  {
  var a = $(".a2").click(function(){
    $(this);
    });
  var b = $(".a4").click(function(){
    $(this);
    });
  }
sessionStorage.setItem("data", a);
sessionStorage.setItem("data1", b);
</script>
<style>
.a1 {
  width      : 310px;
  height     : 400px;
  border     : 2px solid red;
  display    : inline-block;
  margin-top : 100px;
  }
.a4 {
  border  : 1px solid gray;
  padding : 5px;
  }
.a2 {
  border  : 1px solid gray;
  padding : 5px;
}
</style>
</body>
</html>
```

if i click an `a1` of first first value i want it to give first first value and first second value inside script tag so that i can make it a session value or i can send it using ajax to next page

if i click an `a1` of first first value i want it to give first first value and first second value inside script tag so that i can make it a session value or i can send it using ajax to next page if i click `a1` i am not getting `a2` or `a4` and i want `a2` and `a4` for which `a1` i clicked if i click on `a1` of first first `a1` i want first first `a1` and first second `a1`

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of redundant code and misunderstandings here (already covered in [my answer to your earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75736417/this-code-in-jquery-giving-me-all-element-i-clicked-by-class-name-a2-instead-of) but it bears repeating here, since you seem to be finding it hard to understand the concepts involved).

You don't need `onclick="on()` *and* `$(".a2").click` at the same time. They both do the same job. And putting one inside the other is even stranger - you don't need to handle the same click twice, or to declare another handler at the time the item is clicked on! Also `$(this);` on its own does nothing at all. And in your scenario, `a` and `b` will contain jQuery objects pointing to the elements selected. It does not contain their values. And since you want to do the same operation on all the elements, you can use a single selector for that. This is neater than having lots of inline event handlers.

All you need is this:

```js
$(".a2, .a4").click(function() {
  console.log($(this).text());
  sessionStorage.add("data", $(this).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="a1">
  <div class="a2" > first first value </div> 
  <div class="a4" > first second value </div> 
</div>
<div class="a1"> 
  <div class="a2" > second first value </div> 
  <div class="a4" > second second value </div> 
</div>
```

N.B. This demo will produce a security error when trying to access Session Storage, because these Stackoverflow demos are in special sandbox which does not have access to it. But that is not relevant - you should be able to use the command successfully in your real environment. I have added a console.log command just to demonstrate that the code runs and can access the data you wanted.

---

Background reading: https://api.jquery.com/click/, https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

I also strongly suggest finding some introductory jQuery and JavaScript tutorials, and following them closely.

Comment: i don't want to click class a2 i want to click class a1 and get a2 class and a4 class as a result of it uniquely

Comment: It makes no difference. In this way, you can get the exact item which was clicked. Did you run the demo? It does what you want. Putting the click event on a1 won't help you.

Comment: If you want different output, then please explain the requirement differently. I have to say that your descriptions are not 100% clear. If writing in English is difficult for you, please find someone to help you translate better. At the very least, adding some punctuation and proper sentences would make it a lot easier to understand! It is written text, not a stream of consciousness.

Comment: i am developing site which needs to click out side the div and give inside element  suppose you are developing a shopping web site and your all product are showing that product is outer div  and on click on it a inner div value its id is called that's why i want a on click outer div to give me inner div value and to send it if using ajax its var value 
lets var a value inside script tag

Comment: Did you read what I said about punctuation? What you are saying is _unreadable_ as one giant unsepearated sentence. It is very hard to understand what you mean. Imagine that I had written my answer without any punctuation...would you be able to understand it?? Please try again.

Comment: `outer div to give me inner div value`...but you can get the inner value by clicking on the inner div, anyway, so it doesn't matter. If my code doesn't do what you want, then you need to explain - with a proper example, in proper, comprehensible English - what you _do_ want it to do.

Comment: you did not understand. I said if you are developing a website that shows products and what product you are showing is outer div and its inner div contains id on clicking on that  outer div that product is clicked and to proceed further we have to pass that id that is inner div hidden so tell me by clicking that product how to get id. means on clicking outer div give me inner div value

Comment: It's true, I didn't understand. I then told you _why_ I didn't understand. But instead of changing how you write, and providing an example as I requested, you just seem to have repeated yourself. If you repeat something that a person does not understand, do you think they will somehow magically understand it the second time?! **Please write in clear, proper English with _punctuation_ and _give an example of what you want the code to do_**. Thankyou.

Comment: https://www.grammarly.com/punctuation

Comment: `to proceed further we have to pass that id that is inner div hidden`... **if** I have understood this correctly (which, as I explained above, is far from certain), it sounds like actually you want to get the value of one specific div from inside the outer div, when it's clicked? And that inner div is hidden? Well, you didn't show anything like that in your original question. I am not a mind-reader. And anyway, it would make a lot more sense to just put the desired into as the `id` of the outer div, or as a `data-`attribute of the outer div. Then it would be easy to retrieve.

Comment: That's not what you asked for originally, though.